# Visual Studio HTML Editor CTRL+

Tags: visual-studio

For many years I used MS Expression Web but moved up to Visual Studio 2015. In Expression Web I could CTRL + Click to follow a link and it would open the page of code related to the link. After spending days trying to figure this out in VS, I have to ask if anyone knows how this works in VS?